# Trading veiw Lightweight graph set timescale at one hour

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts, lightweight-processes, candlesticks, lightweight-stream-api

I am currently using lightweight chart for my candlestick graph but i am facing an issue . How can i set my data in candle stick.

My data.

```
"data": [
  {
    "open": "1.18384",
    "high": "1.1845",
    "low": "1.18368",
    "close": "1.18429",
    "date": "2020-08-20 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "open": "1.18458",
    "high": "1.18483",
    "low": "1.18367",
    "close": "1.18385",
    "date": "2020-08-19 23:00:00"
  },]
```

How can i set this data need help!

Answer (score -1):

Your data have to be correctly formatted as in:

- all OHLC data have to be numbers, not string
- date needs to be named `time`

Here's an example:

```
[
    {
        time: '2018-12-22',
        open: 162.81,
        high: 167.96,
        low: 160.17,
        close: 160.48,
    },
    {
        time: '2018-12-24',
        open: 160.16,
        high: 161.4,
        low: 158.09,
        close: 158.14,
    },
]
```